# не могу найти файл jupyter_notebook_config.py на Mac

Tags: python

Друзья, добрый день. Не могу найти файл jupyter_notebook_config.py на Mac. 
Показывает путь ( Overwrite /Users/mvv/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py with default config? [y/N] ), но в папке mvv  нет папки  или файла  .jupyter . Подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: С маком никогда не работал, но в линуксе папки, начинающиеся с точки, - скрытые и так просто их не увидишь.

Comment: Да, погуглил, мак тоже прячет имена, начинающиеся с точки, попробуйте сделать в соответствии с этой инструкцией: http://remontka.pro/hidden-files-folders-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

В маке как и в линуксе всё, что начинается с точки - скрыто. То есть папка .jupyter скрыта